# Surface integral (stokes?)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I want to solve the following problem, I want to find

$$ \iint_S x \, \mathrm{d}S $$ where S is the part of the parabolic cylinder that lies inside of 
the cylinder $z = x^2/2$, and in the first octant of the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1$

I was obviously thinking about switching to cylindrical coordinates, but I have problems
setting up the problem and finding the limits.

Could I get some tips / help ? =)

Comment: I'd like to help you, but I don't get the picture. This is a 3D plot of your 2 equations. http://cl.ly/1v3J1i2v1V392u352b2g
Can you describe to me again on which surface you want to find your integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main challenge here is finding a suitable parametrization. Since the boundary of the surface of integration is defined in terms of a cylinder, it makes sense to try cylindrical coordinates. We have:

$$
(x, y, z) = (\rho\cos\phi, \rho\sin\phi, z)
$$

Since $\displaystyle z = \frac{x^2}{2}$, the parabolic cylinder has the following parametrization in cylindrical coordinates:

$$
(x, y, z) = \left(\rho\cos\phi, \rho\sin\phi, \frac{(\rho\cos\phi)^2}{2}\right)
$$

And the ranges are:

$$
\rho \in [0, 1], \phi \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]
$$

Here is a plot of this parametric representation:

[image: plot]

From there, you have a straightforward surface integral to solve.

Comment: I thought for a moment that $\rho \in [0,1/2]$ does the 1 come from the fact that it lies inside of $x^2+y^2=1$ ?
Then I get $$\mathrm{d}S = \| \dot{r}_\rho \times \dot{r}_\phi \| = \sqrt{1 - \rho^2(\phi)} \rho \mathrm{d}\rho \mathrm{d}\phi$$
but this seems wrong. I end up with some elliptic integral, where is my mistake ?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar In the X-Y plane, $x^2+y^2=1$ is a circle with radius $1$, so $\rho$ changes from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar As for $dS$, I think you made a mistake there. Can you edit the question to show how you derived that?